# Who owns the "Defenders of the Earth" IP?

Tags: defenders-of-the-earth

I remember watching the *Defenders of the Earth* cartoon when I was a child. As far as I am aware (I may be wrong) the 3 characters that form The Defenders, the Phantom, Mandrake and Flash Gordon, do not have modern day comics and despite rumors, no films appear to be upcoming. Given the financials behind superhero movies nowadays this seems surprising.

Who owns the various rights (film, comic etc) to the 3 as a team, or individually if they are not owned by a single entity?

Comment: I believe King Feature Syndicates still owns the overall rights to the team and the characters. Warner Brothers picked up the film rights to Mandrake the Magician in 2012, but indeed, it doesn't look like they've done anything with it. All three characters are still being published as newspaper comics.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Interestingly, the last time they optioned a Defenders film right was 1994. But they've optioned rights to the individual characters several times since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[King Features Syndicate](http://kingfeatures.com/licensing/licensed-brands/) (part of the Hearst Corporation) own the IP, [trademarks](https://trademarks.ipo.gov.uk/ipo-tmowner/page/search?id=201116&domain=1) and licences (national and international) for all three original Defenders; Flash Gordon, The Phantom and Mandrake the Magician. This includes the team name as well as all of the minor characters who appeared in the shows and comics.

[image]

You might want to note that all three characters are *currently* appearing in their own comic serials, reprinted worldwide, so the copyrights and trademarks aren't likely to end any time soon.

> **Flash Gordon:**
>
> King Features Syndicate, the **owner of the property and distributor of
> the comic strip**, continues to expand the domestic and international
> licensing portfolio in support of the Flash Gordon franchise.

and

> **Mandrake**
>
> Created by Lee Falk in 1934 for King Features Syndicate, it is still flourishing in papers around the globe. Mandrake the Magician appears six days a week as a daily strip in the United States, Canada, Jamaica, Mexico, India, Finland, Colombia, El Salvador and Portugal.

and

> **The Phantom Turns 80**
>
> The Phantom has also been experiencing solid sales of licensed merchandise at both brick-and-mortar and online retailers all around the world, including Radical Enterprises, which has brought Phantom tees to The Entertainment Store, India’s one-stop shop for pop culture and fan merchandise. The Phantom apparel is also being featured at Jack & Jones, the men’s fashion retailer in India; Sprinter Sport & Style in Spain and Kid Collective in Australia and New Zealand. Bamford Watch released a limited-edition Phantom Rolex watch while The Bradford Exchange in Australia and New Zealand offers unique, limited-edition collectibles and fine gifts. An 80th anniversary silver commemorative coin is available via Perth Bullion Co. in Australia, New Zealand, Europe, Asia, the United States and Canada and a collectible stamp series has just been released by the Australia Post. Frew and Egmont will also publish special 80th anniversary commemorative Phantom comic books. Zynga, leading developer of the world’s most popular social games, has also tapped The Phantom.